# How to use the local Parameters in Routes

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Every one,
I am having problem while getting the local parameter and then passing it in the routes. 
I am having this code in the routes/middleware.js

```
exports.detectLang = function(req, res, next) {
var match = req.url.match(/^\/(de|en)([\/\?].*)?$/i);

if (match) {
    req.setLocale(match[1]);
    // Make locale available in template
    // (necessary until i18n 0.6.x)
    res.locals.locale = req.getLocale();
    // reset the URL for routing


    req.url = match[2] || '/';
    console.log(response);
} else {
    // Here you can redirect to default locale if you want
    console.log("does not match")
}

next();
     };
```

This detects the de or en part in the url and set the local variable "Locale" with the de or en

Now in the routes/view/index.js

I want to get that Local Parameter "Locale" and put it in routes
something like this

```
    // Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    // Views

    app.get('/'+locale, routes.views.index);

    app.all('/'+locale+'employees', routes.views.employees);

};
```

But I am not able to get that locale parameter from middle ware to the index.js

Comment: Why not make use of a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a param, 'locale', in your route:

```
app.get('/:locale', routes.views.index);
```

...and then make use of the param in your middleware:

```
var match = req.params.locale.match(/^\/(de|en)([\/\?].*)?$/i);
```